# PyPy Error: AttributeError: No symbol SCDynamicStoreCopyProxies found in library <None>

Tags: macos, pypy

I have a program on my Mac, and I think it is too slow. I want to use pypy to speed it up.
I got pypy's binary distribution for mac, and I ran `./pypy -m pip install ...`. It said that I need to run ensurepip. But when I ran it, it raised this error:

```
  File "/Users/Andy/Downloads/pypy3.7-v7.3.3-osx64/lib-python/3/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Users/Andy/Downloads/pypy3.7-v7.3.3-osx64/lib-python/3/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/Andy/Downloads/pypy3.7-v7.3.3-osx64/lib-python/3/ensurepip/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(ensurepip._main())
  File "/Users/Andy/Downloads/pypy3.7-v7.3.3-osx64/lib-python/3/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 214, in _main
    default_pip=args.default_pip,
  File "/Users/Andy/Downloads/pypy3.7-v7.3.3-osx64/lib-python/3/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 127, in _bootstrap
    return _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
  File "/Users/Andy/Downloads/pypy3.7-v7.3.3-osx64/lib-python/3/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 32, in _run_pip
    runpy.run_module("pip", run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)
  File "/Users/Andy/Downloads/pypy3.7-v7.3.3-osx64/lib-python/3/runpy.py", line 208, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "/Users/Andy/Downloads/pypy3.7-v7.3.3-osx64/lib-python/3/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/Users/Andy/Downloads/pypy3.7-v7.3.3-osx64/lib-python/3/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/var/folders/v8/6phlhg3j00b85wfb6_sh7syh0000gn/T/tmpjikdylze/pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__main__.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "/var/folders/v8/6phlhg3j00b85wfb6_sh7syh0000gn/T/tmpjikdylze/pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
  File "/var/folders/v8/6phlhg3j00b85wfb6_sh7syh0000gn/T/tmpjikdylze/pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 104, in create_command
  File "/Users/Andy/Downloads/pypy3.7-v7.3.3-osx64/lib-python/3/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1015, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 976, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 647, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/var/folders/v8/6phlhg3j00b85wfb6_sh7syh0000gn/T/tmpjikdylze/pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "/var/folders/v8/6phlhg3j00b85wfb6_sh7syh0000gn/T/tmpjikdylze/pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "/var/folders/v8/6phlhg3j00b85wfb6_sh7syh0000gn/T/tmpjikdylze/pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "/var/folders/v8/6phlhg3j00b85wfb6_sh7syh0000gn/T/tmpjikdylze/pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "/var/folders/v8/6phlhg3j00b85wfb6_sh7syh0000gn/T/tmpjikdylze/pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/html5lib/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
  File "/var/folders/v8/6phlhg3j00b85wfb6_sh7syh0000gn/T/tmpjikdylze/pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/html5lib/serializer.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "/Users/Andy/Downloads/pypy3.7-v7.3.3-osx64/lib-python/3/xml/sax/saxutils.py", line 6, in <module>
    import os, urllib.parse, urllib.request
  File "/Users/Andy/Downloads/pypy3.7-v7.3.3-osx64/lib-python/3/urllib/request.py", line 2618, in <module>
    from _scproxy import _get_proxy_settings, _get_proxies
  File "/Users/Andy/Downloads/pypy3.7-v7.3.3-osx64/lib_pypy/_scproxy.py", line 64, in <module>
    ffi = _CFSetup()
  File "/Users/Andy/Downloads/pypy3.7-v7.3.3-osx64/lib_pypy/_scproxy.py", line 63, in _CFSetup
    return CFProxy()
  File "/Users/Andy/Downloads/pypy3.7-v7.3.3-osx64/lib_pypy/_scproxy.py", line 52, in __init__
    func = getattr(mod, fname)
  File "/Users/Andy/Downloads/pypy3.7-v7.3.3-osx64/lib-python/3/ctypes/__init__.py", line 382, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/Users/Andy/Downloads/pypy3.7-v7.3.3-osx64/lib-python/3/ctypes/__init__.py", line 387, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
  File "/Users/Andy/Downloads/pypy3.7-v7.3.3-osx64/lib_pypy/_ctypes/function.py", line 255, in __init__
    ptr = self._getfuncptr([], ctypes.c_int)
  File "/Users/Andy/Downloads/pypy3.7-v7.3.3-osx64/lib_pypy/_ctypes/function.py", line 442, in _getfuncptr
    self._ptr = cdll.getfunc(self.name, ffi_argtypes, ffi_restype)
AttributeError: No symbol SCDynamicStoreCopyProxies found in library <None>
```

What's wrong with it? Please help me! Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [issue 3314](https://foss.heptapod.net/pypy/pypy/-/issues/3314) and has been fixed in the [nightly builds](http://buildbot.pypy.org/nightly/py3.7/). We are waiting for confirmation that the issue is fixed, so please comment on the issue.

Comment: I'm still facing the same issue. Unsure how you fixed it?