# Install older pypy3 version with homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew, pypy

Due to this issue [PyPy Error: AttributeError: No symbol SCDynamicStoreCopyProxies found in library <None>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66038554/pypy-error-attributeerror-no-symbol-scdynamicstorecopyproxies-found-in-library)
the current pypy3 version in homebrew is basically unusable for me.

I see the issue has been fixed in the pypy3 nightly builds, but I would like to avoid going through all the hoops of installing that. Is there an easy way to, for the time being, install an older pypy3 version via homebrew?
There does not seem to be a pypy3@7.3.2 available.

Trying this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7787703/9978001 gives me

```
Invalid usage: Installation of pypy3 from a GitHub commit URL is unsupported!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, older PyPy versions will not work on BigSur (macos11)